# Using Pagination getting System.Collections.Generic.List does not contain a definition for error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, pagination

I have a Project that I need to add Pagination to but I keep getting an error when loading it up.  I found this link, [http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application/), on the MSDN site.  I am working through it  put this code in my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult TechOpenTickets(int? page)
{

      ViewBag.Title = "Open Tickets Assigned To Me";

      var model = FindTechTickets(new Guid(Properties.Settings.Default.ActiveID));

      int pageSize = 3;
      int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
      return View("TechOpen", model.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));

}

private IEnumerable<Ticket> FindTechTickets(Guid ticketStatusId)
{
      Guid g = Guid.Parse(Session["LoggedUserID"] as string);

      return db.Tickets
           .Include(t => t.TicketNotes)
           .Where(t => t.TechnicianId == g).Where(t => t.TicketStatusId == ticketStatusId)
           .OrderBy(t => t.OpenDate)
           .ToList();

}
```

and then in my view, I have this at the top:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<HelpDesk.Model.Ticket>
@using PagedList;
```

I am receiving the following error when on the 'Return View...' line in my Controller.

> '`System.Collections.Generic.List<HelpDesk.Model.Ticket>`' does not
>   contain a definition for 'ToPagedList'

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the return type of FindTechTicckets(...)?

Comment: Do you have `using PagedList;` in your controller class?

Comment: @alex, it is Dynamic.  I will add the code above for you to see.

Comment: Why `dynamic` instead of `IEnumerable<Ticket>` or `List<Ticket>`?

Comment: @JasonP it has been dynamic for a while and worked before I added the pagination.  I can change it to List<ticket> but would that fix my issue?

Comment: I don't know if it will solve the problem, I just think that's a bad use of `dynamic`. You know the type at compile time, so use it. Also, `PagedList.PagedListExtensions.ToPagedList<T>(this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>, int, int)` is an extension method in the `PagedList` namespace. So if you have a `using` for `PagedList` in your controller, it should work.

Comment: just changed that Jason.